# The key-down event invalid in zoom out when using ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript in EPSG:3826

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am a new to ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript. I have a problem when the tileLayer load in, and the zoom controller I set in the top-right is not work well. The plus button can only be invoked event two or three times, and then not working any more, and the minus button can work well. In another aspect of moues, the mouse-wheel event can zoom out/in in perfect behavior.  my version is 4.10, my environment is node.js with express, the code snippet is as following:

```
const basemap = new Basemap({
    baseLayers: [
        new TileLayer({
            url: "https://arcgis.tpgos.gov.taipei/arcgis/rest/services/ED/GD_Plain_Service/MapServer",
            title: "Basemap",
            crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
            spatialReference: {
                wkid: 102443
            }
        })
    ],
    title: "basemap",
    id: "basemap",
    spatialReference: {
        wkid: 102443
    }
});


// Create a map using the MapImageLayer
var map = new Map({
    basemap: basemap
});


var view = new MapView({
    container: "divmap",
    map: map,
    zoom: 3,
    extent: {
        xmin: 296938.73458000005,
        ymin: 2776832.77203,
        xmax: 301876.2566600001,
        ymax: 2781271.34259,
    },
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    spatialReference: {
        wkid: 102443
    } // Set the spatial reference
    //spatialReference: { wkid: 102100 } // Set the spatial reference
});
view.ui.move("zoom", "top-right");
```

Do you know the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: I would recommend using version 4.23, there it work without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With version ArcGIS Maps SDK JS 4.23 it works without any problems.

But to make it work correctly you have to also specify CRS for the view extent:

```
var view = new MapView({
  container: "divmap",
  map: map,
  zoom: 3,
  extent: {
    xmin: 296938.73458000005,
    ymin: 2776832.77203,
    xmax: 301876.2566600001,
    ymax: 2781271.34259,
    spatialReference: {
      wkid: 102443
    }
  },
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  spatialReference: {
    wkid: 102443
  }
});
```